# Glue Gun Glue as USB flash drive case?

Tags: insulation, glue

I have a little USB flash drive which the plastic cover has broken off of. It still works fine, but I often have the thing in my pocket or in the bottom of my bag. I don't want the bare board to get damaged by my keys or something. Would covering the board in glue from a hot glue gun be a reasonable casing to protect it?

I've used glue gun glue to help hold together and insulate small arduino circuits before without any troubles, so my intuition tells me that this should be fine, but my experience lies more on the software side of things, so I'd like to check with a few others before I attempt this.

Comment: In general, epoxy glues are used on electronics. "Gun glue", which is sometimes used, often has reliability problems which appear after some time.

Comment: Glue gun glue is *damn hot* so hot that it often exceeds even the maximum storage rating of lots of ICs.

Answer (score 4):

A suitably-sized piece of heat-shrink tubing can be effective on this sort of board.

Answer (score 2):

Use epoxy compound for such tasks.

You can cast it very well and it has good mechanical and electrical properties.

Get transparent one and if you want you can color it by some ball pen ink.

Comment: Be aware that some epoxies have undesirable electrical effects, may produce significant heat when curing, and may cause mechanical stress if curing shrinkage is large.  Further, epoxy potting will strengthen an object overall, but will also transfer external stresses to the object since they are mechanically linked throughout the object, and not at predefined points. An epoxied keyfob will likely be stronger than an unprotected one, but it's not as good as the original case. All this and you won't be able to repair it or recover data when it does break since epoxy removal is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Glue gun glue is flexible, it won't protect the device against bending.

Comment: That is a good point. I hadn't thought much about bending.